# Why can't I use babel package?

Tags: texmaker, babel

I'm using TexMaker in Xubuntu. I wrote these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\title{Os devaneios da pós-graduação de Luís Muniz}
\author{Luís Augusto Muniz Telles}
\date{\today}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%
"Paulo batista mito"
\end{document}
```

When I click on the button to compile, it gives me this error:

```
#"Package babel error: unknown option 'portuguese'. Either you mispelled it  
 (babel)      or the language definition file portugues.ldf was not found."
```

I already tried the options `portuges`, `brazilian` and `brazil` and it gives me the same error.

*Note:* I just installed TexMaker and tried it out.

Comment: 'ello, Welcome to TeX.sx! Are you using TeX and friends through Ubuntu's packaging system or the vanilla one from TUG? If it's the former, there might be some missing dependency, say, `texlive-lang-portuguese`. `:)`

Comment: Ahhhh, I went to the Ubuntu's Software Center and downloaded 'texlive-lang-portuguese' and now it works! Thanks, very much!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>From my comment to a proper answer. `:)`</sub>

This looks like a missing dependency in the TeX installation. Running

```
$ sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-portuguese
```

in the terminal (or installing the very same package via Software Center) will install the Portuguese support for `babel` and hopefully the code will work. `:)`

---

Also, the format of the document should be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % to have good hyphenation
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % accented characters in input
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
%
\title{Os devaneios da pós-graduação de Luís Muniz}
\author{Luís Augusto Muniz Telles}
\date{\today}
%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%
``Paulo batista mito''
\end{document}
```

Comment: Deve ser muito engraçado este Paulo Batista