# I selected Portuguese as main language, but the titles (chapter, figure, bibliography) are always in Dutch

Tags: xetex, memoir, babel, languages

I use:

- class `memoir`
- package `babel`
- package `biblatex-abnt`
- Manjaro Linux

I run and compile:

- `biber` (`biblatex`)
- XeLaTeX

I also have tried to switch the languages several times, but they are always in Dutch instead of Portuguese. I put my native language in the first and also in the last of the languages in the package `babel`. I also tried to add `portuguese` to `memoir` and `biblatex`, but always in Dutch. And `biber, at sometimes, classified wrongly as Dutch, German and Spanish.

Here is the small and minimal code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, oldfontcommands, dvipsnames]{memoir}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[backend = biber, dateabbrev = false, giveninits, ittitles, justify, sorting = nyt, style = abnt, url = true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referencias.bib}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}

\usepackage[portugues, dutch, english, french, italian, ngerman, spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\selectlanguage{portugues}

\begin{document}

    \chapter*{Abstracto}

    Bom dia!

    \selectlanguage{english}
    \chapter*{Abstract}

    Good morning!

    \selectlanguage{french}
    \chapter*{Abstract}

    Bonjour !

    \selectlanguage{spanish}
    \chapter*{Abstracto}

    ¡Buenos días!

    \selectlanguage{italian}
    \chapter*{Riassunto}

    Buonggiorno!

    \selectlanguage{ngerman}
    \chapter*{Abstract}

    Guten Tag!

    \selectlanguage{dutch}
    \chapter*{Overzicht}

    Goedemorgen!

    \selectlanguage{portugues}


    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables

    \nocite{*}
    \begin{raggedright}
    \printbibliography
    \end{raggedright}

\end{document}
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### Log

[Log file](https://gist.github.com/gusbemacbe/6430d5ea7a6570a311867201993259aa)

Yes, I have Portuguese installed.

Which packages were caused by `catoptions`? Here is the list of packages (yes, many packages, because I am using @gcedo's[Thesis Polimi](https://github.com/gcedo/master-thesis)).

```
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, shapes}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{abraces}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\hyphenation{da-ta-base}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{newverbs}
\usepackage{verbments}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{memhfixc}
\usepackage{pacotes/infoBulle/infoBulle}
```

Comment: Observe that if I change from `portuguese` to `brazil`, the document will still be in Dutch.

Comment: Make sure to make this into a single example instead of asking people to make several files to test your example. There is no need to include that abstract, it could just as well be in the document. Also is the biblatex/biber stuff necessary because you are not providing any bib data for others to test.

Comment: ```Package babel Error: Unknown language `portuguese'``` does not sound good. Are you sure you have installed the Portuguese language module?

Comment: Please follow daleif's request and try to minimise your example. Ideally you would only have one file (without `biblatex` or Biber, they are not relevant here, I think). Do you really need all the languages in your example to show the issue or would two be enough?

Comment: I have no issues using upstream TeXLive 2018, I don't speak dutch or portuguese, but Conteúdo, Lista de Figuras and Lista de Tabelas sounds quite portuguese to me

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204136/35864  might be of interest.

Comment: I mrged two files into one files. Yes, I have Portuguese installed, here is the screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/VAYQCAl.png. And the LaTeX Wikibooks has suggested me `portuguese `brazilian` and `brazil`, but the document still was in Dutch.

Comment: The screenshot only shows `portuges.sty`, but you need `portuges.ldf`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204136/35864.

Comment: Manjaro Linux does not have the package `texlive-lang-portuguese`, but I installed `texlive-full` and `texlive-langextra`, and the document is still in Dutch.

Comment: Do you have `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-portuges/` or `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/babel-portuges/`?

Comment: Yes, it does. Here is the screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/yezvzWP.png

Comment: What does `kpsewhich portuges.ldf` give in a terminal?

Comment: `kpsewhich portuges.ldf
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-portuges/portuges.ldf`

Comment: For this specific example, please post the entire log file. Note that the bib screen shot you provided does not match the MWE

Comment: My log has 4,8k lines, do I must attach a fil or copy the whole log?

Comment: That list of packages is a mess: Several packages are loaded multiple times (either explicitly like `\usepackage{pgfplotstable}` or implicitly by other packages that load them). I seriously doubt that you need all of those packages. The longer you continue with that massive list, the more risk you run of everything blowing up at some point. I suggest you start over from a clean preamble and only load the packages you really need.

Comment: The `menukeys` package loads `catoptions`

Comment: Too bad, I have just skipped ones packages and will stop using templates (because @gcedo used all these packages in his template, except `menukeys`, that he shared at the question about beautiful typography here in TeX). I have removed the package `menukeys`, my thesis returned to Portuguese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MWE works fine for me, but the `.log` file you show (which is from a *different* document) suggests that `catoptions` is loaded.

The following MWE reproduces the undesirable behaviour for me (not only is the output in Dutch, I also get two errors)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage[dutch, portuguese]{babel}

\begin{document}
Lorem \refname

  \tableofcontents
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables
\end{document}
```

Apparently `catoptions` messes with `babel`'s option handling so heavily that it completely destroys the mapping from `portuguese` to the internal name `portuges`.

Solution 1: **Don't load `catoptions` (or the package(s) that load it) unless you really need it and know why you load it.**

Solution 2: Load `babel` before `catoptions` (or the package(s) that load it).

Solution 3: Load `babel` with the option `portuges` instead of `portuguese`. (For historically reasons the Portuguese language module is internally called `portuges` in `babel`, the name `portuguese` is resolved as a convenience option and `catoptions` disables the handling of that option.)

See also [Error when using xwatermark and babel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/443158/35864)

---

The package `menukeys` in your updated list of packages is the one that loads `catoptions`. I strongly suggest you do not load all the packages you list in your question – I can hardly imagine that you need all of them. The template you link to has not been updated in two years and I doubt there is going to be a lot of support for it.

Comment: I do not have package `catoptions`. I will test now.

Comment: @GustavoReis Your `.log` file says otherwise. Quite likely a package you or you template loads loads `catoptions` internally.

Comment: I have searched `catoptions` in all files and I did not find `catoptions`. I will attach the log and the file.

Comment: @GustavoReis Your log file has `Package catoptions Warning: Undefined options` this can happen only if your file loads `catoptions`. As I say it might be that your file doesn't load `catoptions` directly, another package your file loads might load `catoptions` internally. In that case you can't easily see who loaded it.

Comment: By chance were the packages `caption` and `pgfplots` caused by `catoptions`? Ihave them.

Comment: @GustavoReis No, neither `caption` and `pgfplots` were loaded by `catoptions` nor do they load it.

Comment: You need to create an MWE that actually gives this problem. xwatermark seems the most likely candidate

Comment: In the log file, locate the first instance of `catoptions` then trace back to see which file is actually loading it.

Comment: I have just updated, attaching a file together with a log.

Comment: That is not an mwe, please make it into something we can copy and test as is, so we do not have to make assumptions or guesses that end up being wrong

Comment: But do I must copy the whole log of 4,8k? I have read MWE several times and tried to improve my question.

Comment: Too bad, I have just skipped ones packages and will stop using templates (because @gcedo used all these packages in his template, except `menukeys`, that he shared at the question about beautiful typography here in TeX). I have removed the package `menukeys`, my thesis returned to Portuguese.

Comment: I have contacted the developer of menukeys. I also will contact the owner of that template.

Comment: Hi, I got your mail, but I don’t have the time to work on `menukeys` at the moment … sorry

Comment: @GustavoReis ^^^^^See Tobi's comment above.

Comment: @Oo'- please note that for a few years now, `menukeys` no longer loads `catoptions` (but it used to be the case).