# Why does loading `newenviron` cause compilation to fail?

Tags: errors, environments, grouping

*To avoid unnecessary effort, please note that I'm asking **specifically about the error's cause**, as opposed to how to avoid it. Furthermore, I'm aware that `\NewDocumentEnvironment` now offers the `b` option.*

Consider the following MNWE,

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{newenviron}
\begin{document}
hylo
\end{document}
```

This fails to compile, claiming there's an extra `\endgroup`, so that `\document` ends with `\endgroup`.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./prawf.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-10-10>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newenviron/newenviron.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/catoptions/catoptions.sty))
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \let \BeforeStartOfDocument \@firstofone \cpt@beforest...
l.199 \begin{document}
                      
?
```

What causes this error exactly?

Comment: `newenviron` (opposing to the `environ` package) loads `catoptions`. `catoptions` in turn redefines many of LaTeX's internals. Some few years ago changes in the LaTeX kernel finally lead to `catoptions` being incompatible with it in such a way that it actually breaks with an error. Previously `catoptions` did break LaTeX, but silently... Search this site, there are a few questions regarding `catoptions`.

Comment: Another example of `catoptions` breaking stuff (before it became incompatible): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461783/i-selected-portuguese-as-main-language-but-the-titles-chapter-figure-bibliog

Comment: The aim of `newenviron` was to allow nested calls of environments defined with `\newenviron`, in order to avoid some shortcomings of `environ` which only used `\BODY`. The idea was nice, but Bruno's implementation of the `b` argument type for `\NewDocumentEnvironment` is much better (and doesn't break LaTeX).

Comment: @egreg Thanks. This wasn't actually the right question, but David had answered before I realised that.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks. Hopefully this will be of use to somebody as a pointer. (It's not actually the right question because I screwed up.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While adding the hook code a couple of years back, some details of the `\document` command changed, in order to add the hooks, which means that packages that patched `\document`  may have made assumptions that are no longer valid. `catoptions` as used here was always intentionally changing latex internals in unsupported ways, and finally it broke and has not so far been updated.

In practice most uses of `newenviron` (and `environ`) packages are better done these days with the `\NewDocumentEnvironment` `b` argument type which does not require any package to be loaded.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it was trying to use `b` which got me into trouble in the first place, but I think that's actually due to some other change. If environments of these kinds are nested, is it better for the outer one to use `environ` if the inner one does? Or is it OK for the outer one to use `b`, even if the inner uses `environ`?

Comment: @cfr it should be ok to nest environ with b or the other way round.