Having trouble passing macro into pythontex function
I have a macro that plugs into a python function.
\newcommand{\transliterate}[6] 
{
    \py{transliterate.process("#1", "#2", in_str, nativize = #4, pre_options = [#5], post_options = [#6])}
}

\newcommand{\itransToTelugu}[1]
{
    \transliterate{ITRANS}{Telugu}{#1}{False}{""}{"TeluguArasunnaChandrabindu", "RetainTeluguDanda", "RetainTeluguNumerals"}
}

I'm having trouble when I'm trying to pass a macro into the function. It is interpreting it literally (probably because of the quotes) and just passing the name of the macro into the function. I'm using the newenviron package.
\usepackage{newenviron}

\newenviron{telugu}
{
    \itransToTelugu{\telugubody}
}

When this is executed, the argument passed into the python function is "\telugubody" instead of the actual body. How do I tell LaTeX to expand this macro out?

If you use a recent version of LaTeX then newenviron would produce an error (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699780/why-does-loading-newenviron-cause-compilation-to-fail). If you indeed get this error as well then anything after it is no longer guaranteed to work correctly. The package should probably be considered obsolete, you can use the environ package instead or the built-in (i.e., available without any packages) \NewDocumentEnvironment command.

Thank you very much! This worked!

@Marijn Would you like to add an answer?

The newenviron package is not compatible with recent versions of LaTeX, see Why does loading `newenviron` cause compilation to fail?.
Instead you can use the built-in functionality of \NewDocumentEnvironment. The special argument type b stores the body of the environment in argument #1. If needed you can also use +b to preserve multiple paragraphs in the body, which might be of interest for the current use case of calling a transliteration function in Python. In the code below I used the regular b specifier as the question did not provide any example of how the code is called.
Note the I added some end-of-line % characters to avoid unwanted spaces in the output, see What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\newcommand{\transliterate}[1]
{%
\py{"#1"+", "+"#1"}%
}

\newcommand{\itransToTelugu}[1]
{%
\transliterate{#1}%
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{telugu}{b}{% the 'b' argument type stores the body in #1
\itransToTelugu{#1}%
}{}

\begin{document}
Result of Python code:
\begin{telugu}
Print this twice
\end{telugu}
\end{document}

Result:

